# How to calculate the correlation function for a discrete series of data

Tags: statistics, correlation-functions

Using a simulation, I have generated a random field, which is basically a list of complex numbers.

How do I calculate the correlation function of the field? To be more specific: which are the calculations that I need to do by hand?

Thanks

EDIT:

I will try to clarify the question. I have generated a 1-d Gaussian random field. The field is a list of complex numbers

A + B*i

C + D*i
etc...

where both the real and imaginary parts are drawn from a Gaussian distribution with assigned mean and variance.
Now I have to calculate the correlation function of this field, by direct calculation. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange, @johnhenry.  You will find that more detail and motivation in the question gets better answers.  What kind of a field is this?  Does it represent a physical quantity?  Fields are usually defined in space, so a list of complex numbers doesn't sound like a typical field.  Maybe this is actually a simulation of a time series?

Comment: It's the Fourier transform of a density field in configuration space

Comment: Did you look at the definition of "correlation function"? What about it is unclear?

Comment: Of course I looked at the definition, but I'm not able to "implement" practically in this case. I guess I have to make products and then an average...but products between which elements?

Comment: If you don't get this reopeneing, you might want to consider posting this over at [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @KyleKanos many thanks, I have done that while I wait for reopening http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131112/calculating-correlation-function-for-a-discrete-series-of-data

Comment: Hmm, I guess you didn't read the part where I suggested *waiting*. Since you didn't wait, I suggest you list this link over at Cross-Validated, stating that it was cross-posted here.